# Is it bad manner to pass elders while walking?

Tags: masjid, greetings

I read somewhere that one should not walk in front of an elder person. But what if an elder person walking in front of me is really slow and I just overtake him and be on my way. Is it a bad manner? I mean I am not really walking "with" him, but I am merely passing him.

Also, is there any restricted times when one should not give Salam to anyone (except when they are in prayer)? Say I pray behind an Imam and when going out of the mosque I see him and give Salam to him. Is it ok considering I just prayed behind him?

Please only answer if your answer is something you are sure about and not something you just saw someone else doing without knowing the source.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Respect of elders is a must in Islam. How this respect is shown vary from culture to culture and time to time. If, in your culture, it is considered rude to pass by an elder, then you should not do that.

If you come face to face to a person, it is good to say "Salam". If he is at some distance, you can skip it. Choose what is the norm in your society.